# tablesorter - Don't want the Footer to sort

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using an asp.net repeater control with tablesorter.
How can i disable sorting on the footer.I have a total on the footer but i don't want sorting to apply.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: i would post some code, overall, <tfoot> will not be sorted with the jquery tablesorter plugin.

Comment: its sorting.The footer does sorting

Comment: I echo my previous sentiments. Posting a code snippet will allow us to disect whats happening better. I am not familiar with asp.net, is this tablesorter an asp tool, a hand-rolled scripit, the jquery tablesorter plugin, or something else.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't detailed enough its the jquery tablesorter plugin.Chrs